# error : ';' expected but 'else' found

Tags: scala

I wrote the following simple code:

```
def Commas(n: Long) = {
  if (n >= 1000)
    Commas(n/1000)
    print(","+ n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
  else
    print(n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
}
```

While it seems correct to me, there is an error. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The `If...else...` syntax expects a statement. You can use a surrounding code block to ensure your code works as expected. Something like(also note that you have to specify return type to `Unit` or just remove the `=` sign):

```
def Commas(n: Long) {
  if (n >= 1000) {
    Commas(n/1000)
    print(","+ n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
  }
  else 
    print(n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def Commas(n: Long) = {
if (n >= 1000) {
    Commas(n/1000)
    print(","+ n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10);
}
 else {
    print(n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10);
}
```

Comment: it gives me a different error: recursive method Commas needs result type

Comment: @user2206758 well then give it a type. `def Commas(n: Long): Unit = ...`

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This solution is for the similar error but not the same situation.*

I have faced the same error. The mistake I did was, I copy pasted the command prompt code to file and forget to remove the pipe (|) character in the lines for the function and got the same error. If you come to this page due to that reason, now you can fix it. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

While, you've got two solutions on how to fix it, here's why it is not working as you expect it to: [Conditional expressions](http://iainmcgin.github.com/scala-ref-markdown/#conditional-expressions) in scala expect [expressions](http://iainmcgin.github.com/scala-ref-markdown/#expressions) in their `if` and `else` blocks. There are several ways to make several expressions (like you have there) into one compound expression (and you can see examples of those in other answers to your question).

Answer (score -1):

Or try this:

```
def Commas(n: Long) = {
    if (n >= 1000)
        Commas(n/1000); print(","+ n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
     else 
        print(n%1000/100 + n%100/10 + n%10)
}
```

Comment: -1: Wrong answer; adding several expression on a single line doesn't produce a single expression.